# How to display HTML with angular when entities are passed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I execute the HTML entities to display the html character?

For example:

I have this string:

```
$scope.myString = "&lt;analysis mode=&quot;baseball&quot; ftype=&quot;&quot; version=&quot; 1.83499&quot; product=&quot;MDFDFAS&quot; sequenceNumber=&quot;14&quot;/&gt;";
```

When I try to output this in a pre tag, it doesn't render.

```
<pre>{{ myString }}</pre>
```

It's exactly as the string is defined.  How do I have the pre tag render the html?

Comment: where and how are you declaring that string? In a controller?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml):

```
<pre ng-bind-html="myString"></pre>
```

Please note, you will need to include the `ngSanitize` module.

Answer (score 0):

Other way of displaying HTML without ngSanitize module.

Try using [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) ([trustAsHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml))

controller:

```
mainApp.controller("mainController", ['$scope', '$sce',
    function ($scope, $sce) {
        $scope.myString = '<b><i>"&lt;analysis mode=&quot;baseball&quot; ftype=&quot;&quot; version=&quot; 1.83499&quot; product=&quot;MDFDFAS&quot; sequenceNumber=&quot;14&quot;/&gt;";</i></b>';

        $scope.renderHtml = function (html_code) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
        }
}]);
```

View:

```
<p data-ng-bind-html="renderHtml(myString)"></p>
```